# How can I read h3 and after text element with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to read  `<h3>` and text between `<h3>` so I want create a json model like title: text,text,text for h3 and text without ad.

```
{
  "title": "text,text,text",
  "title": "text",
  "title": "text",
  ...
}
```

How can I do it in this case with Java or Kotlin?

```
<div class="biri" id="biri">
    <h1>Yoksa Birisi mi itti?</h1>
    <h3>Title</h3>Text,
    <br>Text,
    <br>Text.
    <h3>Title:</h3>Text
    <h3>Title:</h3>Text
    <div class="ad">
        <div style="max-width:336px;">
            <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
            <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-7180771993103993" data-ad-slot="2897611612" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
            <script>
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Title</h3>Text:
    <b>Text:</b> (Text
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all `h3` tags by using `Document.select()`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
List<String> h3s = doc.select("h3").stream()
        .map(Element::text)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This extracts the content of all `h3` tags and collects the content of them. The result is this:

```
[Title, Title:, Title:, Title]
```

Beside that the JSON, you want to create is not valid, because the keys in an JSON object have to be unique, so you can not have multiple `h3` keys.

Comment: Is "Title": "Text,Text,Text" not possible?

Comment: "Text,Text,Text" is not in the `h3` element.

Comment: No, that is not possible with this html. You maybe can use a regex for that, if the content does not change.